# Node.js endpoint is not working but another one is working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 endpoints in Node.js index.js file.

First one is working well and it turns 200 OK. But the second one is not working, it turns 404 Error. I could not find the reason.

First endpoint is /AddArac. It works well and adds data to MongoDB database
Second endpoint is /AddMesaj. It doesn't work. Both endpoints have the same logic.

My nodejs file is here:

`

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var objectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
mongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Connection Fail', err);
    }
    else {

        var db = client.db('basaranSMSDev');

        //Add arac
        app.post('/AddArac', (request, response, next) => {

            var data = request.body;
            var name = data.name;
            var plaka = data.plaka;
            var tel = data.tel;

            var json = { 'name': name, 'plaka': plaka, 'tel': tel };

            db.collection('Araclar').find({ 'plaka': plaka }).count(function (error, number) {

                if (number > 0) {
                    response.json('Araç daha önce kaydedilmiş.');
                }
                else {
                    db.collection('Araclar').insertOne(json, function (error, res) {
                        if (err) {
                            response.json('Araç kaydında hata oluştu tekrar deneyiniz.');
                            console.log('Arac eklenemedi', err);
                        }
                        else {
                            response.json('Araç eklendi');
                            console.log('Arac eklendi.');

                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        });

        //Araç listesi getirme

        //add mesaj
        app.post('AddMesaj', (request, response, next) => {
            var data_mes = request.body;
            var plaka = data_mes.plaka;
            var mtext = data_mes.text;
            var driver = data_mes.driver;
            var date = data_mes.tarih;

            var json = { 'plaka': plaka, 'text': mtext, 'driver': driver, 'date': date };

            db.collection('Mesajlar').insertOne(json, function (error, res) {
                if (err) {
                    response.json('Mesaj gönderiminde hata oluştu tekrar deneyiniz.');
                    console.log('Mesaj eklenemedi', err);
                }
                else {
                    response.json('Mesaj gönderildi');
                    console.log('Mesaj eklendi.');

                }
            });

        });

        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('Connection ok');
        });
        //Mesaj listesi getirme

    }
}
    );
```

`

Comment: there is a typo in app.post('AddMesaj'....change it to /AddMesaj

Comment: @rags2riches Oh okay thank you.

Comment: beside, try to separate your application logic from your modules, this code as it stands is hard to test, hard to maintain and hard to develop. Imagine if you want to add more routes or more handlers...

Comment: I will consider it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
app.post('/AddMesaj', (request, response, next) => {
```